# Can I make navbars display navs on computer and direct to new url on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 4 navtabs that when pressed display different #navs. On mobile I would like them to display nothing when clicked and instead direct to a specific url. Anyone got an idea as to how this would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap hide and show `nav` tags - use different nav url in `<li>` tags

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Below nav Visible only in Mobile-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light visible-xs">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--Below nav will be hide in Mobile view-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light hidden-xs">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#link1">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#link3">Link 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

**Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/**